# I don't know how to prove a simple theorem used with fixpoint in Coq

Tags: coq

I am a beginner in coq and want to prove the following theorem t1. First I used `induction i` and `destruct j`, but it got bogged down in the middle.
I would like some hints for this problem.

Function f takes two arguments of nat and returns Prop (e.g., f 2 4 = x 2 ∧ x 3 ∧ x 4 ∧ x 5).

Theorem t1 shows that a head of function f can be cut and concatenated (e.g., x 3 ∧ f 4 7 ⇔ f 3 8).

```
Parameter x : nat -> Prop.

Fixpoint f (o i : nat) : Prop :=
 match i with
 | S O =>  x (i+o-1)
 | S i' => f o i' /\ x (i+o-1)
 | _ => True
 end.

Theorem t1 : forall i j : nat, 
    x i /\ f (S i) j <-> f i (S j).
Proof. Admitted.
```

Comment: I feel like this question belongs to Stackoverflow because it is about [getting the proof done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686164/existential-instantiation-and-generalization-in-coq#comment13880496_10686164) and not about some concept of CS.

Comment: I tend to agree: this seems to be about using Coq, not the principles of using proof assistants (which would be ontopic, I guess). What's your take, @AndrejBauer? Community votes, please!

Comment: Yeah, possibly. There'll be more of this in the future, so we should have a policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, let's simplify `f` just a little bit, keeping the special case when it doesn't let the trailing `/\ True` to appear in the generated proposition (I also renamed the parameter names to make them correspond to the ones used by the theorem below):

```
Fixpoint f' (i j : nat) : Prop :=
 match j with
 | 0 => True
 | 1 => x i
 | S j' => f' i j' /\ x (j' + i)
 end.
```

Now we can `destruct j`, take care of `j = 0` case, then use `induction` on `j` again. Throwing in some automation we get the following:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Theorem t1 : forall i j : nat,
  x i /\ f' (S i) j <-> f' i (S j).
Proof.
  destruct j.
  - easy.
  - induction j; firstorder; now rewrite Nat.add_succ_r in *.
Qed.
```

Notice that the structure of the proof mimics the definition of `f'`: we treat the cases `j = 0`, `j = 1` separately and then use the induction hypothesis (under the hood, `firstorder` does that) to prove the recursive case.

Answer (score 6):

You are making your life difficult by defining things in convoluted ways. Here's how a better definition of the same thing makes the proof easy.

```
Fixpoint f_better n0 len : Prop :=
  match len with
  | 0 => True
  | S k => x n0 /\ f_better (S n0) k
end.

Theorem t1_better: forall n0 len,
    x n0 /\ f_better (S n0) len <-> f_better n0 (S len).
Proof.
  easy.
Qed.
```

If you really insist on using your version, we can prove that as well, but it'll be painful.

Comment: Thank you for adding a comment. I wasn't aware that f can be simplified to say so.